# how to put every list tag on each other?

Tags: html, css, breadcrumbs

I'm new in `css` and `html` I have three `<ol>` `<li>` a tags. I wanna put every new  tag under another a tag I use z-index and relative position but it doesn't work for me and every new tag go on previous tag. how can i solve this problem with `css` .
here is my jsfiddle [code](http://jsfiddle.net/xxrxtrm4/)

Comment: In order to use `z-index` you need `position: ...`. Not sure what you are trying to do but try `position: absolute;`.

Comment: i use relative position but doesnt have any result

Comment: is li tag , i put jsfiddle tag you can see my code

Comment: Could you be more precise what you are trying to do.

Comment: cant you use jquery/javascript?...

Comment: i want to make something like this http://www.demo.stylifyyourblog.com/2012/07/lazy-load-buttons-v2.html

Comment: you may alter z-index for each `li` dynamically using jquery.

Comment: If you are able to use jquery, you may achieve something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/uepop2tz/

Answer (score -1):

I think you want something like this:

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/winolo/1/edit)**

(Was clear as soon I've seen you use border-left.)

```
.breadcrumb {
  position:absolute; /* this one will position your OL to the right */
  right:0;
  list-style: none; 
  overflow: hidden; 
}

.breadcrumb li{
  display:inline-block; /* align horizontally LI elements */
}

.breadcrumb li a {
  display:inline-block; /* allows to use paddings etc on inline elements */
  border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 -20px 0 0;
  padding: 10px 22px 10px 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background-color: blue;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
}
```

So basically,

- no, you don't need `z-index` at all.
- you don't need `float`